# Issue building a REST API query using $filter for Power BI Admin API

Tags: python, rest, powerbi

I am trying to access a Power BI Admin API by filtering the status of dataset refreshes that are failed, however the API filter query doesn't work.

Here is the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/getrefreshables

Below is part my code in Python for calling Get method, which is failing -

```
refreshables_url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/capacities/refreshables?$filter=lastRefresh/status eq 'Failed'"
header = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
r = requests.get(url=refreshables_url, headers=header)
```

Below error is thrown when I try to filter for status -

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value",s,err.value") from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

However, when I tried below, it works fine for such simple queries without inner/nested elements.

```
refreshables_url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/capacities/refreshables?$filter=averageDuration gt 1200"

refreshables_url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/capacities/refreshables?$filter=refreshesPerDay eq 15"
```

However, when I try to filter for inner array like Status, it fails. I must be calling it incorrectly but not sure of it.

What am I missing here?

Here is how the response looks like -

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
      "name": "SalesMarketing",
      "kind": "Dataset",
      "startTime": "2017-06-13T09:25:43.153Z",
      "endTime": "2017-06-19T11:22:32.445Z",
      "refreshCount": 22,
      "refreshFailures": 0,
      "averageDuration": 289.3814,
      "medianDuration": 268.6245,
      "refreshesPerDay": 11,
      "lastRefresh": {
        "refreshType": "ViaApi",
        "startTime": "2017-06-13T09:25:43.153Z",
        "endTime": "2017-06-13T09:31:43.153Z",
        "status": "Completed",
        "requestId": "9399bb89-25d1-44f8-8576-136d7e9014b1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what am expecting (it should just be filtering the entries for status as "Failed" instead of above "completed" entries -

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "ewrffbeb1-6337-460c-326e-a46fb27hh234",
      "name": "SalesMarketing",
      "kind": "Dataset",
      "startTime": "2017-06-13T09:25:43.153Z",
      "endTime": "2017-06-19T11:22:32.445Z",
      "refreshCount": 2,
      "refreshFailures": 0,
      "averageDuration": 189.3814,
      "medianDuration": 168.6245,
      "refreshesPerDay": 1,
      "lastRefresh": {
        "refreshType": "ViaApi",
        "startTime": "2017-04-13T09:25:43.153Z",
        "endTime": "2017-10-13T09:31:43.153Z",
        "status": "Failed",
        "requestId": "43643bb89-25d1-77f8-8543-dsgfewre9034r3223"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You say "doesn't work" and "is failing", but you don't show any output or errors, no one will be able to help with so little information. Please include full stack trace in case of an error, or the outputs that you're getting vs. what you were expecting. More generally, have a look at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention the error. I have updated the content now. What am expecting is same output but for those entries with Status filtered as "Failed" instead of "Completed" ones.

Comment: Is there documentation on how to use `$filter` in the API queries. I have a similar problem, and I cannot find any. Microsoft's documentation of the API mentions that you can use `$filter` in some of the API queries but it does not explains how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The filter fails because status isn't actually a string but an enum. The annoying part is that the actual enum values are different from the labels sent by the API. So the 'Unknown' status actually has an enum value of '0', 'Completed' is '1', and 'Failed' is '2'. Haven't found those values documented anywhere, just found them by poking the API, but anyway this means that you can filter like this:

```
$filter=(cast(lastRefresh/status, 'Edm.String') eq '2'
```

Or like this:

```
$filter=lastRefresh/status eq Microsoft.PowerBI.ServiceContracts.Api.DatasetRefreshHistoryStatus'2'
```